# Like Vish and Shiv have reverse spelling and opposite effects, does Sita and Sati have some reason behind their names?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, sita, sati-goddess

As per our Vedic literature, Vish (Vishnu) means creator and Shiv (Shiva) means evil destroyer. I was wondering similar word-meaning similarity between Sati and Sita. Is there any historical evidence for their names as like in Vish & Shiv?

Thanks

Comment: This concept of 'Vish and Shiv' is not a Hindu concept AFAIK. One cannot take a few syllables of a name and rearrange the letters... and Visham (with the big Sha) means poison) and Shiva (with the small Sha) means auspicious.

Comment: In which part of India do people call Vishnu as just "Vish"? Original Sanskrit names विष्णु and शिव (read in Sanskrit not Hindi) has no reverse spelling for them. Literal meaning of विष्णु  is "one who pervades" and शिव  is "auspicious". Sita means **furrow** as she was found during ploughing of land. I think Sati means women of good conduct or good wife.

Comment: The only sensible anagram I have found is Nama(ha) and Mana(ha)

Answer (score 7):

There are no concepts like you are saying.

The dhatu 'Vish' means Pervading.

The dhatu 'Shiv' means Auspicious.

In what sense are you seeing evil destruction in Auspicious?

Hence, they are not opposite by no ways.

The name 'Sita' means furrow as she was born while Janaka was ploughing.

The name 'Sati' from dhatu 'Sat' which have several meanings like truth, existence. Also Sati means extremely chaste women.